# View per tenant in aspnetboilerplate

Tags: multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

Okay , agreed that aspnetboilerplate features multi-tenancy and provides the features of single instance - multiple database etc.
However I would be interested in having  views/css per tenant .
something in the lines of

```
/views/{tenant}/Index.cshtml
```

which would call

```
/contents/{tenant}/site.css
```

& no... tenants are not known at run-time....they are dynamic

Comment: If it is not known at run-time, when is it known? When your application is shut down?

Comment: How would you create custom files for tenants that are not known? What is the difference in each file?

Comment: okay.....now lets say the tenants are know at run time....how am i supposed to call the respective views per tenant

Comment: Specify the tenant?

Comment: if you want to customize a CSHTML or CSS  you can do it in your CSHTML file. add conditional imports to your CSHTML that's it.